# Fade effect being applied to the adjacent ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, flexbuilder

I am applying `s:Fade` effect on `s:ItemRenderer` on `mouseOver` event. The fade effect *ends* fine, but *during* its execution, it is applied only on **half** of the `ItemRenderer` object, plus half of the **adjacent** (right) `ItemRenderer`.

`ItemRenderer` objects are inside a `s:List` which uses a `HorizontalLayout`.

Here is the code for the `ItemRenderer` called `FilterTagRenderer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="false"
                mouseOver="{fadeIn.play()}"
                mouseOut="{alpha = 0.6}"
                alpha="0.6">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Fade id="fadeIn" alphaTo="1" duration="500" target="{this}"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Label id="lblFilterName" text="{data}" paddingBottom="5" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="14"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Here is the code for `List`:

```
    <s:List id="filterValuesList" width="{this.width}" borderVisible="false"
    itemRenderer="view.FilterTagRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout id="flowLayout" gap="6"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>
```

I am using Flex SDK 4.0.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in flex or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which Flex SDK version are you using? And some actual code will be useful, too.

Comment: @GeorgiHristozov: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something a little bit wrong, in that with Spark components you should let the state change run th effect, rather than trying to run it yourself. However, effects under the hood are just a filter on a single DisplayObject, so I'm not sure how you can get an effect that's partially on two different objects. Your renderers are probably just not where you think they are. What happens if you use one of the layouts that came with Flex, such as TileLayout?

Comment: I am using HorizontalLayout, which comes with Flex, no?

Comment: BTW, I also tried using effects that are synchronized with state transitions, same error!

And regarding your comment about probably renderers don't know where they are: the effect _ends_ fine, meaning that the alpha is increased on the desired itemrenderer only.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the id of flowLayout and thought you were using the third party flow layout. (http://saturnboy.com/2009/10/flow-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug.

Steps to reproduce: simply compile and run the following two files, and then move the mouse over to any word.

Application file (FadeBug.mxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'.split(' '))}"
            itemRenderer="BuggyItemRenderer" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout gap="6"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>

</s:Application>
```

BuggyItemRenderer.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="false"
                alpha="0.4"
                mouseOver="{fadeEffect.play()}"
                mouseOut="itemrenderer1_mouseOutHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function itemrenderer1_mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (fadeEffect.isPlaying) {
                    fadeEffect.stop();
                }
                this.alpha = 0.4;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Fade id="fadeEffect" target="{this}" alphaFrom="0.4" alphaTo="1"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Label text="{data}" fontSize="25" fontWeight="bold"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```